# Flutter validator only trigger on double tap

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, widget

i stored phone numbers in a firebase document(table). What i want is to detect if the number already existed by using validators and display a message under a textbox that the phone number is already exists i had no problem with this , my problem is a have to double tap the button to execute to complete the task.

```
   var _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
   var validate;

   String validateNumber(String value){
      if (value.isEmpty) {
        return 'Please enter number';
      }if(validate == true){
        return "Phone number already exists";
      }
      return null;
    }

   addPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) async{
      var exist = await db.checkPhoneNumber(phoneNumber); //my query to firestore so far i have no problem with this.
      if(exist == true){
         validate = true;
          print(validate);
      }
      if(exist == false){
        validate = false;
        Navigator.of(context).push(_verifyPhone(_phoneNumber.text));
        await db.addPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
      }
  }                  //my function to detect if the number exists

    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _get1();
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
             key:_formKey,
             child:Expanded(
              child:Scrollbar(
                child: ListView(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                  children: <Widget>[
        
                      TextFormField(
                              controller: _phoneNumber,
                              validator: validateNumber,                      //my validator
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
             ),
            ),
            FlatButton(
                  onTap: (){
                    if(_formKey.currentState.validate()){
                     addPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    }
                  
                  },
                )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the `validate()` method on your form state. Look [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormState/validate.html) for API reference.

This is not invoked automatically by the framework for you. You need to invoke it inside the `onTap()` method of your button. Add there a line `_formKey.currentState.validate()`.

When this method is invoked then the form calls the `validator` for each form field.

---------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------

Ok, @ppdy, you are one step closer now. It doesn't work yet because your validator only checks if the value is not empty. Just look carefully at what happens when you push the button. It runs the `validateNumber` and if the value is empty the framework will render your validate message. Then if the value is not empty you run the `addPhoneNumber` method, but you run it yourself. This is important, notice that it is not get run as part of the text form field `validator` property function. So you need to handle the output of the `await db.checkPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);` yourself and render the validation red message in the text form field if the check is false.

For this please note first that the `TextFormField` class has the `decoration` property. Type of this property is the `InputDecoration`. Please read the documentation of this class [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration-class.html). So by setting the `errorText` property of the decoration you will be able to add the red validation message to the form field manually.

Try to think it all over, play with it, stick this all together and you will have what you want :)

Comment: hello please check the edited code still does not works

Comment: can someone help me on this?

Comment: I've added some more info to the answer.